# Jade: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, iteration, pug, sequelize.js

I have a issue with the jade iteration.
I want iterate sequelize query results on my jade page.

index.js

```
router.get('/new/:name', function(req, res) {
models.Event
    .findAll({attributes: ['incoming', 'event'], raw: true})
    .then(function (items) {
        // var results = items;
        console.log('FIND ALL EVENT AND INCOMING', items);
        res.render('templates/new/' + req.params.name, {eventList: items});
        // res.json(results);
    });
});
```

event.jade

```
ul
    each event in eventList // this is a test
        li!= event.event
```

command prompt

```
TypeError: C:\Users\FORFIRM\Desktop\promos\views\templates\new\event.jade:31
29|             span.title Inserimento records tramite form
30|             ul
31|                 each list in eventList
32|                     each item in list
33|                         li #{item}
34|             .margin
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Where i wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're not setting a pug variable. Jade (now Pug) won't read a JavaScript variable. You have to do something like this https://codepen.io/azat-io/pen/dMKbKJ

Comment: The result doesn't change! In another job i've used the same system, but in that case, it has worked.

Comment: ok, can you put the code up on codepen or somewhere?